# TokenMismatchException Laravel 5 & BackboneJs

Tags: ajax, laravel, backbone.js, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am developing a Laravel 5-BackboneJs Application. I'm using RESTful Resource controllers to make my own api.

I've got a Backbone model then I am calling save model method. It makes an ajax request like this:

```
gerencia.app/es/customrole/1
```

That's why I am trying tu update the model with id 1.

Backbone creates a request with PUT method:

[image: Request Information]

But it gives me 500 internal server error! I see the preview then:

[image: Request preview]

This is a TokenMismatchException from Laravel, then I've found I've got to send a token so I did this in my blade view:

```
<meta name="token" content="{{ Session::token() }}">
```

Then I've create a function to set the token and add this function to ajax beforeSend method:

```
function sendAuth( request ){

    console.log( request );

    return request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='token']").attr('content'));

}

model.save({
    beforeSend: sendAuth,
    success: function(){
        console.log( 'success!' );
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log( 'error!' );
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work in spite of I see the token in request headers :(

[image: request headers]

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working by following the instructions on the Laravel site. I added this to my global layout file:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Then, I created a JS file called `csrf-token.js`, and placed this code in it:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

After doing that, the POST requests from Backbone worked correctly and I can see the extra header in the request.  The key for me was to include the `csrf-token.js` file AFTER Backbone:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/lib/backbone-min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/csrf-token.js') }}"></script>
```

I guess Backbone overwrites the ajax setup options when it loads, so you need to include your changes after that.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to add a new key/value called token in my model method:

```
model.save({
    "_token" : $("meta[name='token']").attr('content'),
    success: function(){
        console.log( 'success!' );
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log( 'error!' );
    }
});
```

You can post another solution to this issue.